# Finding Lipschitz constant for a matrix funcion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the Lipschitz constant for $F(U)={\rm tr}(A^TU^T\Sigma UA)$ where $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $\Sigma$ is positive definite. My steps were as follows:

1. ${\rm tr}(A^TU^T\Sigma UA)={\rm tr}(AA^TU^T\Sigma U)$
2. diagonalizing $\Sigma$ and $AA^T$ to $P\Lambda P^T$ and
   $Q\Lambda'Q^T$  and since $U\in O(n)$ we can calculate the Lipschitz
   constant for ${\rm tr}(\Lambda' U^T\Lambda U)$
3. Last expression can be written as $\sum_{i,j}u_{ij}^2\mu_{i}\lambda_j$ where $\mu_i$'s and $\lambda_j$'s are eigenvalues of $A^T A$ and $\Sigma$ respectively.

And I am stuck afterwards. Any helps would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $U_1,U_2$. Since $U_1,U_2\in O(n)$, $\|U\|_2=1$. I will use the matrix $2$-norm throughout the answer.

Then
$$
\begin{split}
|tr(A^TU_1^T\Sigma U_1 A)-tr(A^TU_2^T\Sigma U_2 A)| &\le
|tr(A^T(U_1-U_2)^T\Sigma U_1 A)|+|tr(A^TU_2^T\Sigma (U_1-U_2) A)| \\
& \le \|tr\|\cdot \|A\|^2 \cdot \|\Sigma\| \cdot \|U_1-U_2\|(\|U_1\|+\|U_2\|)\\
& \le 2 \|tr\|\cdot \|A\|^2 \cdot \|\Sigma\| \cdot \|U_1-U_2\|.
\end{split}
$$
Here, $\|tr\|$ is the norm of the trace-operator from $\mathbb R^{n,n}$ to $\mathbb R$,
$$
\|tr\| =\sup_{A\in \mathbb R^{n,n}\setminus\{0\}} \frac{|tr(A)|}{\|A\|},
$$
not to be confused with the trace norm of the matrix, which is defined using singular values.

The estimate uses sub-multiplicativity of the matrix norm that is induced by vector norm. The induced norms are sub-multiplicativ regardless of the underlying spaces, in particular, the matrices can be rectangular, see [Induced norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm). The definition I used is
$$
\|A\|:=\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2},
$$
with $\|\cdot\|_2$ being the standard Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but apparently there is a misunderstanding... :)
${\rm tr}$ is matrix trace. I thought it was clear.

Comment: And in any case I don't know how you ended up canceling $U$ from the equation....

Comment: That was a disastrous error. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much. Vote up. But isn't submultiplicativity only holds for square matrices? Plus shouldn't trace norm be defined with respect to a matrix? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms

Comment: See edit. It is the norm of the trace mapping, not the trace norm of a matrix.

Comment: Thaks a lot. But the definition of submultiplicativity there comes with being square right.

Comment: No. It works for any combination of rectangular matrices as long as their product is defined.

Comment: may I ask for a reference for that? Plus I am completely unable to calculate the trace norm. Can you please help me on where can I read about it?

Comment: These two questions should be posed as questions on their own on the site imho.